# Adding values to array in nested

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to add values to an array using the code below but it only seems to result in 1 item (last in the loop) being added to the array.

```
$awin_products = array();

foreach($awinprices as $value){
foreach($value as $obj){        
    $awin_products[name] = (string)$obj->sName;
    $awin_products[imageUrl] = (string)$obj->sAwThumbUrl;
    }
}
print_r($awin_products);
```

This is probably quite simple to fix but so far I've not found an answer.

EDIT: I am looking for this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Item 1 Name
            [imageUrl] => http://example.com/item1.jpg
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Item 2 Name
            [imageUrl] => http://example.com/item2.jpg
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Item 3 Name
            [imageUrl] => http://example.com/item3.jpg
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Item 4 Name
            [imageUrl] => http://example.com/item4.jpg
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need following

```
$awin_products = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($awinprices as $value){
    foreach($value as $obj){        
        $awin_products[$i]['name'] = (string)$obj->sName;
        $awin_products[$i]['imageUrl'] = (string)$obj->sAwThumbUrl;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Then you'll get structure like this:

```
Array
(
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name
                    [imageUrl] => url
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name1
                    [imageUrl] => url1
                )
)
```

Comment: @sr83 it was hard to get what you want since you didn't posted desired structure. See edited answer

Answer (score 4):

You're over-writing the same values on each run:

```
foreach($value as $obj){         
    $awin_products[name] = (string)$obj->sName; 
    $awin_products[imageUrl] = (string)$obj->sAwThumbUrl; 
}
```

You need to change where you're writing to; maybe with something like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($awinprices as $value){ 
    $awin_products[$i] = array();
    foreach($value as $obj){  
        $awin_products[$i][]['name'] = (string)$obj->sName; 
        $awin_products[$i][]['imageUrl'] = (string)$obj->sAwThumbUrl; 
    } 
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Or even better `$awin_products[$i]['name']`

Comment: You're right - that is more elegant. Can you edit my answer to add it?

Comment: nerdklers wrote what i was thinkin about

Comment: In this solution array will be overwritten for each `$awinprices`

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov - I think that edit should solve it. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @andrewsi yeah, now its exactly as mine :)